# How do I send XML as the email body from a native iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing an app that ultimately wants to send some XML via email.

I have the mailto/URL thing sussed, thanks to various links on the interweb, including [Brandon](http://icodeblog.com/2009/02/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-openurl-to-send-email-from-your-app/) and [Simon Maddox](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5314-send-email-attachment.html).

So I can send emails with the xml formatted using square brackets ([ ]), rather than the usual angle brackets (< >).  But when I send angle brackets, with the XML mangled using the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding call, It treats it as HTML and just prints the values.

If change them to "& lt;" and "& gt;" then it totally strips the XML out... (I know there should not be a space after the & - but the SO formatter turns them into <,>...)

I tried adding some HTML in front to see if that helped, to no avail.

I don't suppose anyone has done this?

Perhaps in-app email is the easy route for me to go... must look into that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me... I have SIP message data containing <> that needed escaping.

```
/* remember to call urlEscapeStringDone to free the malloced string.. */
char *urlEscapeString(char *str)
{
    int i, l;
    char *escStr;

    escStr = malloc(strlen(str)*3 + 1);
    if(!escStr) return NULL;

    memset(escStr, 0, strlen(str)*3);

    l = strlen(escStr);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];

        /* < and > handling for HTML interpreters.. (apple mail) */
        if(c == '<')
        {
            strcat(escStr, "%26lt%3b");
            l += 8;
        }
        else if(c == '>')
        {
            strcat(escStr, "%26gt%3b");
            l += 8;
        }
        else if(must_escape(c))
        {
            char tmp[3];

            sprintf(tmp, "%02x", (unsigned) c);
            escStr[l] = '%'; l++;
            escStr[l] = tmp[0]; l++;
            escStr[l] = tmp[1]; l++;
        }
        else
        {
            escStr[l] = str[i];
            l++;
        }
    }

    printf("escaped: %s\n", escStr);

    return escStr;
}

void urlEscapeStringDone(char *str)
{
    if(str) free(str);
}

int must_escape(char c)
{
    char *allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._";

    if(!strchr(allowedChars, c)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try replacing all the '<' and '>' characters with '&lt'  and '&gt' after you had wrapped it in the basic HTML headers?

As I understand it, this is the usual technique to display XML on a web page.

Comment: Yes, see my edit above - although when you say "wrap in HTML", I tried prefixing with a <p>, <div> only - no closing tag... maybe that would help...